# How to generate random numbers without repetition

Tags: java, android

I generate a random number with this code :

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
```

I want to ***stop generating duplicate*** numbers and I want to generate a new number after my app opens again.

**how can I do ?**

Comment: maintain number in file/DB and keep on updating the same...

Comment: You can use a `List` with all the permissible random numbers, then remove elements as they are generated

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe what you really need is a GUID?

Comment: I don't thik that `int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 7);` is enough to generate a GUID.

Answer (score 2):

Store the numbers you generate in a `Set`. Then every time you generate a new random number, test that it's not already present in this `Set`.

```
Set<Integer> nums = new HashSet<Integer>();

// Initialize set on app boot

int rnum;
do {
  rnum = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
} while (!nums.contains(rnum));

// Update the set
nums.add(rnum);

// Use rnum now..
```

You'll also need to persist the `Set` values before your app shuts down; in `onPause()` or `onStop()` method. You could use `SharedPreferences` or simply serialize/deserialize the `Set`. Using a database would be an overkill.

Comment: So the more numbers you generated, the more attempts it will take to generate the next one...

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: create array

Step 2: Fill array with proper numbers

Step 3: Shuffle array.

```
private Integer[] randomNumbersRange(int numberRange) {
    //Create and shuffle array
    Integer[] randomNumbers = new Integer[numberRange];
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = 1 + i;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(randomNumbers));
    return randomNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could ensure there are no duplicates;

```
public int generateRandomNumber(){
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final int lastNumber = sp.getInt("lastNumber", 0);
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
while(randomNumber == lastNumber){
randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() *7);
}
sp.edit().putInt("lastNumber", randomNumber).apply();
return randomNumber;
}
```

Edit: Here is a dumb way to do what you want:

```
String _p = sp.getString("previousNumbers", "");
String[] previousNumbers = _p.split(";");
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
while(Arrays.asList(previousNumbers).contains(Integer.toString(randomNumber))
{
randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
}
_p.concat(Integer.toString(randomNumber) + ";");
sp.edit().putString("previousNumbers",_p).apply();
return randomNumber;
```

Comment: But this method won't persist the generated numbers between reboots. `I want to stop generate dupilcate number and I want to generate a new number after my app opens again.`

Comment: @DerGolem maitain your generated number in some db table or local file and update on every number creation and also check weather it is created before or not.

Comment: Also this method doesn't keep track of historical numbers except the last one generated...

Comment: @Dipen_a Thank you. But I didn't want to know the answer. Since I didn't ask the question.

Comment: @Solarnum But this edit now saves only the last generated number, not all the previous ones.

Comment: Edited again with the easiest way I could think of effectively doing this without building a db...

Answer (score 0):

To generate distinct value at every app open you can use

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

This will return a `long` instead of `int`

Comment: And how is this related to the OP's question?

Comment: He need a distinct value,he never said to revolve around random number

Comment: No, the question is: `I want to stop generate dupilcate number and I want to generate a new number after my app opens again.`. Which really seems to have nothing to deal with this answer.

Comment: So, this will never generate duplicate value plus generate something new every time

Comment: And how will it generate a number which is compliant to the range (0, 7)? `int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 7);` And which is different everytime the app is started (so, some kind of persistance is required)?

Comment: This is basically what he is doing. i just tried to make him think in another direction. He always need a new value,he never said it to be int . if he just want something direct with app start i just gave him,instead of using collections or sharedPrefrences

Comment: @DerGolem you are right at your part but question open many directions because it lacks in actual implementation of why this was needed .

Comment: The points are (this is what I understood): **1** He wants a number between 0 and 7. **2** He wants them persisted (so not to repeat them on different runs). Does your answer satisfy **any** of these points?

Comment: I think let the OP judge. Anyway you can down vote any time. its your right

Comment: No, I don't feel like.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps check out seeding your number with the system timestamp, or some other value you persist outside the application (in storage / a db / etc).

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#setSeed(long)

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a suggestion

Comment: Yea, the question is difficult to answer directly. The user is asking for something to generate 'a' non duplicate random number on startup. It sounds like a potential seeding problem, not having any more data that that.